# Confusion on how `kur.engine.Engine._evaluate` works

Tags: python

**The problem**

There seems to be a conflict on the use of `kur.engine.Engine._evaluate`.

When I ran `kur dump mnist.yml` under `kur/example/` directory, and look inside the running details, I got:

[image]

However, when I ran `eng = kur.engine.Engine()` and then `eng._evaluate('mnist-defaults.yml')`, I got the following error:

[image]

**What does the source code say?**

My reading of this function doc:
1. take a string as arg named expression
2. return an python object or class

My reading of this code:
1. I give the function a string arg
2. it returns an error named 'Not Implemented Error'

```
def _evaluate(self, expression):
    """ Evaluates a string expression in the current scope.

        # Arguments

        expression: str. The string to evaluate.

        # Return value

        The evaluated expression (some Python object/class)
    """
    # pdb.set_trace()
    raise NotImplementedError
```

However, in fact it works as the doc says when run in console `kur dump mnist.yml`. So, where my understanding went wrong?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Engine` is an [abstract base class](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-abstract-base-class). This means that it is **not** intended to be directly instantiated. Instead, its derived classes use the base class as a "template" (so-to-speak) for extending its functionality. This is a classic pattern in [object-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_programming)#Abstract_and_concrete), especially in languages like Java and C++. Python is an extremely flexible language, though, and there are lots of ways to accomplish similar design patterns (e.g., the [abc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) module, duck-typing, or classic inheritance plus good documentation and `NotImplementedError`).

In your particular case, when you actually run Kur, the instantiated (run-time) type of your engine is *not* `Engine`; it's `JinjaEngine`. So when the `_evaluate()` call is made, it is actually the `JinjaEngine` which is handling it, not the base class (which, as you correctly point out, raises an exception). Try instantiating a `JinjaEngine` instead, and you should get the expected results.

Comment: Can I understand it in the following practically, using the example I asked above? 

1. when running from console, it is `kur.engine.Engine._evaluate()` working under the hood, return `mnist.yml`, even though in source it only has one line of code `raise NotImplementedError` (without understanding why so)

2. when running from ipython, I have to use `kur.engine.JinjaEngine()._evaluate()` to get result `mnist.yml`.

Comment: Sort of, yes. You definitely are instantiating `Engine`, which, being an abstract base class, shouldn't be done. When Kur is actually running, or if you want to get the intended behavior, then instantiate a `JinjaEngine` instead. Abstract base classes are a way of saying, "This is how this type of objects acts" without actually creating one of the objects; instead, derived classes are responsible for implementing the behavior of the base class. It's a standard OOP pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @ajsyp comment above:

> You definitely are instantiating Engine, which, being an abstract base class, shouldn't be done. When Kur is actually running, or if you want to get the intended behavior, then instantiate a JinjaEngine instead. Abstract base classes are a way of saying, "This is how this type of objects acts" without actually creating one of the objects; instead, derived classes are responsible for implementing the behavior of the base class. It's a standard OOP pattern

If I understand it correctly, when running `kur -vv build mnist.yml` and when I use logger to display the functions at work under `kur.Kurfile.parse_source`, I noticed a few things below:

```
[INFO 2017-04-11 14:05:05,946 kur.kurfile parse:97] (self): after initialize Kurfile object, we parse it: 1. evaluate all section dicts in spec.data with scopes; 2. as a result, spec.data added section aliases (like training, testing);3. other uses here to be answered ....; 4. assign spec.data['templates'] to spec.templates; 3. convert spec.data['model'] into model as containers, and store the list of containers inside spec.contaienrs ; 5. return Nothing
[INFO 2017-04-11 14:05:05,946 kur.kurfile _parse_section:1006]
[DEBUG 2017-04-11 14:05:05,946 kur.kurfile _parse_section:1011] _parse_section(): Parsing Kurfile section: settings
[INFO 2017-04-11 14:05:05,947 kur.engine.engine evaluate:209] (self, expression, recursive=False): Evaluates an string expression in the current scope, as itself: (how does scope help evaluate expression? Not sure how is scope used); if expression is not a string, then do some recursion.
[INFO 2017-04-11 14:05:05,947 kur.engine.engine evaluate:209] (self, expression, recursive=False): Evaluates an string expression in the current scope, as itself: (how does scope help evaluate expression? Not sure how is scope used); if expression is not a string, then do some recursion.
[INFO 2017-04-11 14:05:05,947 kur.engine.engine evaluate:209] (self, expression, recursive=False): Evaluates an string expression in the current scope, as itself: (how does scope help evaluate expression? Not sure how is scope used); if expression is not a string, then do some recursion.
[INFO 2017-04-11 14:05:05,947 kur.engine.engine evaluate:209] (self, expression, recursive=False): Evaluates an string expression in the current scope, as itself: (how does scope help evaluate expression? Not sure how is scope used); if expression is not a string, then do some recursion.
[INFO 2017-04-11 14:05:05,947 kur.kurfile _parse_section:1006]
[DEBUG 2017-04-11 14:05:05,947 kur.kurfile _parse_section:1011] _parse_section(): Parsing Kurfile section: train
[INFO 2017-04-11 14:05:05,947 kur.engine.engine evaluate:209] (self, expression, recursive=False): Evaluates an string expression in the current scope, as itself: (how does scope help evaluate expression? Not sure how is scope used); if expression is not a string, then do some recursion.
[INFO 2017-04-11 14:05:05,948 kur.engine.engine evaluate:209] (self, expression, recursive=False): Evaluates an string expression in the current scope, as itself: (how does scope help evaluate expression? Not sure how is scope used); if expression is not a string, then do some recursion.
[INFO 2017-04-11 14:05:05,948 kur.engine.engine evaluate:209] (self, expression, recursive=False): Evaluates an string expression in the current scope, as itself: (how does scope help evaluate expression? Not sure how is scope used); if expression is not a string, then do some recursion.
[INFO 2017-04-11 14:05:05,948 kur.engine.engine evaluate:209] (self, expression, recursive=False): Evaluates an string expression in the current scope, as itself: (how does scope help evaluate expression? Not sure how is scope used); if expression is not a string, then do some recursion.
[INFO 2017-04-11 14:05:05,948 kur.engine.engine evaluate:209] (self, expression, recursive=False): Evaluates an string expression in the current scope, as itself: (how does scope help evaluate expression? Not sure how is scope used); if expression is not a string, then do some recursion.
[INFO 2017-04-11 14:05:05,948 kur.engine.engine evaluate:209] (self, expression, recursive=False): Evaluates an string expression in the current scope, as itself: (how does scope help evaluate expression? Not sure how is scope used); if expression is not a string, then do some recursion.
[INFO 2017-04-11 14:05:05,948 kur.engine.engine evaluate:209] (self, expression, recursive=False): Evaluates an string expression in the current scope, as itself: (how does scope help evaluate expression? Not sure how is scope used); if expression is not a string, then do some recursion.
[INFO 2017-04-11 14:05:05,948 kur.engine.engine evaluate:209] (self, expression, recursive=False): Evaluates an string expression in the current scope, as itself: (how does scope help evaluate expression? Not sure how is scope used); if expression is not a string, then do some recursion.
[INFO 2017-04-11 14:05:05,948 kur.engine.jinja_engine _evaluate:123] (self, expression): convert a yml expression (a string) to a python object
[INFO 2017-04-11 14:05:05,949 kur.engine.engine evaluate:209] (self, expression, recursive=False): Evaluates an string expression in the current scope, as itself: (how does scope help evaluate expression? Not sure how is scope used); if expression is not a string, then do some recursion.
[INFO 2017-04-11 14:05:05,949 kur.engine.jinja_engine _evaluate:123] (self, expression): convert a yml expression (a string) to a python object
[INFO 2017-04-11 14:05:05,950 kur.engine.engine evaluate:209] (self, expression, recursive=False): Evaluates an string expression in the current scope, as itself: (how does scope help evaluate expression? Not sure how is scope used); if expression is not a string, then do some recursion.
[INFO 2017-04-11 14:05:05,950 kur.engine.jinja_engine _evaluate:123] (self, expression): convert a yml expression (a string) to a python object
[INFO 2017-04-11 14:05:05,951 kur.engine.engine evaluate:209] (self, expression, recursive=False): Evaluates an string expression in the current scope, as itself: (how does scope help evaluate expression? Not sure how is scope used); if expression is not a string, then do some recursion.
[INFO 2017-04-11 14:05:05,951 kur.engine.engine evaluate:209] (self, expression, recursive=False): Evaluates an string expression in the current scope, as itself: (how does scope help evaluate expression? Not sure how is scope used); if expression is not a string, then do some recursion.
[INFO 2017-04-11 14:05:05,951 kur.engine.jinja_engine _evaluate:123] (self, expression): convert a yml expression (a string) to a python object
[INFO 2017-04-11 14:05:05,951 kur.engine.engine evaluate:209] (self, expression, recursive=False): Evaluates an string expression in the current scope, as itself: (how does scope help evaluate expression? Not sure how is scope used); if expression is not a string, then do some recursion.
[INFO 2017-04-11 14:05:05,952 kur.engine.jinja_engine _evaluate:123] (self, expression): convert a yml expression (a string) to a python object
[INFO 2017-04-11 14:05:05,952 kur.engine.engine evaluate:209] (self, expression, recursive=False): Evaluates an string expression in the current scope, as itself: (how does scope help evaluate expression? Not sure how is scope used); if expression is not a string, then do some recursion.
[INFO 2017-04-11 14:05:05,952 kur.engine.jinja_engine _evaluate:123] (self, expression): convert a yml expression (a string) to a python object
[INFO 2017-04-11 14:05:05,953 kur.engine.engine evaluate:209] (self, expression, recursive=False): Evaluates an string expression in the current scope, as itself: (how does scope help evaluate expression? Not sure how is scope used); if expression is not a string, then do some recursion.
```

1. when codes run at `kur.Kurfile.parse`, it parses on different sections like `settings`, `train`, `validate` ...
2. when doing `kur.Kurfile._parse_section`, most section require to run a lot of `kur.engine.engine.Engine.evaluate` and a few if not none of `kur.engine.jinjiaEngine.JinjaEngine._evaluate`

Should I understand the comment and the observations in the following way:

1. `kur.engine.engine.Engine.evaluate`, `kur.engine.engine.Engine._evaluate` are base class methods, practically I don't need to understand the inside of them; is it right?
2. `kur.engine.jinja_engine.JinjaEngine._evaluate` is the derived method from the base methods above, I need to understand its practical meaning for it; is it right?
3. my understanding of `kur.engine.jinja_engine.JinjaEngine._evaluate`: it is to convert a yaml string expression to a python object. Is it correct?

If not, could you explain with an example? (don't have to be working code, just an example we can picture in the mind would be ok too)

Thanks

---

@ajsyp further answers and explanations are very helpful

> 1.) All of the functions defined in the `Engine` class are, by definition, base-class methods. *This does **not** imply that they are not important.* They are incredibly important! To be specific, `Engine.evaluate()` actually does work, trying to figure out how to process your data, what types it is, if recursion is necessary, etc. And `Engine._evaluate` defines the API that the derived classes must implement (although, from a pure code standpoint, `Engine._evaluate()` does not **do** anything, since its job is to define the API, and all implementation is delegated to the derived classes).
>   2.) Yes, `JinjaEngine._evaluate()` is a derived class method. In this particular case, it implements the logic defined by the parent class's API.
>   3.) Kind of. `JinjaEngine._evaluate()` is responsible for using the current values of the Kurfile to evaluate a Jinja2 expression (not a YAML expression; the YAML parser already did that; in fact, you could have used a JSON Kurfile instead, and this entire answer is still true). The evaluated result of the Jinja2 expression is a string representation of a Python expression. So the function also needs to interpret that string, if necessary, to construct the underlying Python type (e.g., the integer 4 versus the string "4").